# Query ignoring conditions because of orwhere - Laravel5

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a product search that makes searching by name , description and also keywords ...

There are 3 columns that contain these items , as follows:
Name, description and keywords

My problem is this , when I do a search for products query returns me a list with several products , but some of them should not be listed for not meeting all the requirements .... follows the query :

My action :

```
public function search( $data )
{
    $products = $this->queryProductsAvailable()
                        ->where('produtos.nome', 'like', '%'.$data.'%')
                        ->orWhere('produtos.descricao', 'like', '%'.$data.'%')
                        ->orWhere('produtos.palavras_chave', 'like', '%'.$data.'%')
                        ->limit( $this->_limitProducts )
                        ->orderBy( 'fornecedores.plano_id', 'DESC' )
                        ->get();

    $this->savePrint( $products );

    // $categories = $this->setCategories();

    return view('Catalogo.search', [
                'products' => $products,
                'searchTerm' => $data
            ]
        );
}


private function queryProductsAvailable()
{   
   return Products::join('fornecedores', 'fornecedores.id', '=' ,'produtos.fornecedor_id')
                        ->where( 'fornecedores.ativo', 1)
                        ->where( 'produtos.moderacao', "P" )
                        ->where( 'produtos.ativo' , true )  
                        ->where( 'produtos.preco_min', '>', 0 )
                        ->select( 'produtos.*');
                        // ->limit( $this->_limitProducts );
}
```

When the query is executed are returned products that are not in the standard of "productsAvailable" which should be fornecedor.ativo = 1 and produtos.ativo = 1 (true)

Despite being implicit in the query , it ignores because of the orWhere clauses .

My doubt is how to not use this orWhere and make my query search the product name , description and also the key words ?

In short , how do I get the products by column name , description and keywords , without ignoring the terms of the function productsAvailable ?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of:

```
$products = $this->queryProductsAvailable()
                    ->where('produtos.nome', 'like', '%'.$data.'%')
                    ->orWhere('produtos.descricao', 'like', '%'.$data.'%')
                    ->orWhere('produtos.palavras_chave', 'like', '%'.$data.'%')
                    ->limit( $this->_limitProducts )
                    ->orderBy( 'fornecedores.plano_id', 'DESC' )
                    ->get();
```

you should use:

```
$products = $this->queryProductsAvailable()
    ->where(function($q) use ($data) {
        $q->where('produtos.nome', 'like', '%'.$data.'%')
            ->orWhere('produtos.descricao', 'like', '%'.$data.'%')
            ->orWhere('produtos.palavras_chave', 'like', '%'.$data.'%')
    })->limit( $this->_limitProducts )
    ->orderBy( 'fornecedores.plano_id', 'DESC' )
    ->get();
```

As you see conditions were wrapped into additional where to add brackets into query

Comment: Thank you!
I will try once again lunch

Comment: That worked! Thank you!

Any article that I can read about this function in the where? I would like to learn more about it .

Comment: @Dayglor The best place to start is the Laravel documentation. Where condition grouping is specifically addressed [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#parameter-grouping).

Comment: Great! Thank you @patricus